# Removing objects from observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

I'm running into a problem with removing objects in an observable array. I have a `removeItemFromQueue` function that should remove the selected object from a queue.

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/horizens/dPduW/2/) shows that if you add a bunch the items to the queue and then remove one, it removes all of them:

```html
<h3>Items:</h3>

<ul data-bind="template: {name:'itemsTemplate', foreach: items}"></ul>

<h3>Queue:</h3>

<ul data-bind="template: {name:'queueTemplate', foreach: queue}"></ul>

<script id="itemsTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li>
        <a href="#">${$data.title}</a> by <a href="#">${$data.description}</a>
        <button data-bind="click: function() {viewModel.removeItemFromPage($data);}">Remove From Page</button>
        <button data-bind="click: function() {viewModel.addItemToQueue($data);}">Add To Queue</button>
    </li>
</script>

<script id="queueTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li>
        <a href="#">${$data.title}</a> by <a href="#">${$data.description}</a>
        <button data-bind="click: function() {viewModel.removeItemFromQueue($data);}">Remove From Queue</button>
    </li>
</script>
```

This is the Javascript:

```
function Item(title, description) {
    this.title = ko.observable(title);
    this.description = ko.observable(description);
}

var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([
        new Item("one", "one description")
    ]),
    queue: ko.observableArray([]),
    addItemToQueue: function (item) {
        this.queue.push(item);
    },
    removeItemFromPage: function (item) {
        this.items.remove(item);
    },
    removeItemFromQueue: function (item) {
        this.queue.remove(item);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I found [this workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/horizens/G6RkC/42/) using `ko.toJS(item)` in the `addItemToQueue` function:

```html
<h3>Items:</h3>

<ul data-bind="template: {name:'itemsTemplate', foreach: items}"></ul>

<h3>Queue:</h3>

<ul data-bind="template: {name:'queueTemplate', foreach: queue}"></ul>

<script id="itemsTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li>
        <a href="#">${$data.title}</a> by <a href="#">${$data.description}</a>
        <button data-bind="click: function() {viewModel.removeItemFromPage($data);}">Remove From Page</button>
        <button data-bind="click: function() {viewModel.addItemToQueue($data);}">Add To Queue</button>
    </li>
</script>

<script id="queueTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li>
        <a href="#">${$data.title}</a> by <a href="#">${$data.description}</a>
        <button data-bind="click: function() {viewModel.removeItemFromQueue($data);}">Remove From Queue</button>
    </li>
</script>
```

And this Javascript:

```
function Item(title, description) {
    this.title = ko.observable(title);
    this.description = ko.observable(description);
}

var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([
        new Item("one", "one description")
    ]),
    queue: ko.observableArray([]),
    addItemToQueue: function (item) {
        this.queue.push(ko.toJS(item));
    },
    removeItemFromPage: function (item) {
        this.items.remove(item);
    },
    removeItemFromQueue: function (item) {
        this.queue.remove(item);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Is there an easier approach?

Also, the cart example here looks to be using similar code to my first example, but does not suffer the same issue with removing items. I'm a bit baffled.

Comment: Here's the cart example: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that you are adding the same item multiple times to your queue array.

The `remove` function of an observableArray will remove all copies of the item that you pass into it.

ko.toJS is one way to get a clean copy of your data.  However, you will lose any observables, if you need them.

Otherwise, you might want to do something like:

`this.queue.push(new Item(item.title(), item.description())` or write a function that will help you make a copy of the item (pass in an item and return a new item).